# Delete method of the Shape object problems

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word document with a number of AutoShapes.

I loop through the shapes by a for loop, and select those with a specific foreColor in order to delete them:

```
For each sh in ActiveDocument.Shapes
 if sh.fill.foreColor = myColor then
  sh.delete
 end if
next i
```

This does not work. However if I replace sh.fill.foreColor with another color for example, it works perfectly.
The more odd is that if I put sh.delete after sh.fill.foreColor = newColor, the first line doesn't execute !! :

```
 For each sh in ActiveDocument.Shapes
     if sh.fill.foreColor = myColor then
      sh.fill.forecolor = newColor
      sh.delete
     end if
 next i
```

According to the documentation, the delete method requires an index argument representing the index of the shape. I tried entering an index, but it doesn't work.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Tank you very much

Comment: When deleting items from a collection while looping over it, it's best to start from the "end" of the collection using something like `For i = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1` and then look at `ActiveDocument.Shapes(i)` in the loop.  It sounds like your shape colors may not be what you think they are though.

Comment: The loop works very well with the other methods not with the delete method. It is not a looping issue in my opinion. If it were, it wouldn't work for any method.

Comment: Note I'm only saying "When deleting items" but you're free to ignore the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer of course. Indeed I didn't read it well. Yet, I tried it just now. Same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see if the output is what you expect:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = activedocument.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        With activedocument.Shapes(i)
            Debug.Print "#: " & i, "Name: " & .Name, "Color: " & .Fill.ForeColor
            If .Fill.ForeColor = 12874308 Then .Delete '<< works fine for me...
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Edit: it's pretty straightforward to demonstrate the problem with using the `For Each` approach. For example this code only deletes half of the shapes in a document on each run:

```
Dim shp 
For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
   shp.Delete
Next shp
```

Comment: The problem is with the delete method not with getting the name/ID/etc (or even changing them which I tried and it works).  What is weird is that the presence of the shape.delete in the for loop prevents all the code in the for loop from executing. If I remove it, the code executes. No error is thrown. I even tried to refer to the shape by ActiveDocument.Shapes(shape.name). It can do anything with it except deleting it.

Comment: Is that your entire code?  feels like there's something significant missing...  If I add in a Delete call it works just fine.

Comment: I would like to thank you. I tried looping from end to begining again and indeed you were right. It works. Do you know why is looping from the end works, not the other way round? Is there a known description of this behavior that I can read to avoid any such issues in the future?

Comment: I've not seen it documented anywhere but you can see similar recommendations on many posts here

Comment: It is not only a "For each" issue. What is weird is that even a for i = 1 to .Shapes.Count does not work. Only counting from end to beginning (as per your suggestion) works. How come the same operation works in a direction but not in the other? Do you understand the reason that makes VBA behave this way?

Comment: The `For i=1 to .Shapes.Count` case is easier to explain.  If you start out with 5 shapes and delete #2 in the loop then what happens when you get to i=5?  The loop limit (.Shapes.Count in this case) is only calculated once when you enter the loop, so the loop will not stop at 4.

Answer (score 0):

@tv share, regaring why: deleting items from a collection in a forward traverse of that collection does not work reliably because each deletion changes the state of the collection:

1. When using a “For i = 1 to SomeCollection.Count … Next i” loop, after each deletion, i no longer refers to the item just deleted, it refers to the subsequent item in the collection.  So when it gets incremented at “Next i", it actually skips over that subsequent item and refers to the item following that one.  The consequence is that such an approach will always delete only half of the items in the collection.
2. Furthermore, the value of the collection’s Count property changes with each deletion so, depending on how the termination condition is defined, it is possible to increment i beyond the end of the collection’s (current) item set, resulting in a run-time error.
3. When using a “For Each Nxt_Item In SomeCollection … Next Nxt_Item” loop, similar problems can arise because, with each deletion, the item that Nxt_Item actually refers to becomes ambiguous with regard to what you expect.

Consequently, as initially pointed out by Tim Williams, when deleting a sequence of items from a collection, it is *always* best practice to traverse the collection in reverse order.